# WP Change Category/Tags URL structure

Tags: wordpress, tags, categories

I need to change tags & categories URL structure from mysite.com/category-name to NUMERIC URL --> mysite.com/random number (For example mysite.com/4393093 something like that) or post ID.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that via WordPress Backend.

**Single post pages**

Change the URL structure for single post pages via Backend settings:

1. Go to dashboard: `example.com/wp-admin/`
2. `Settings` Menu
3. `Permalinks` submenu
4. Select `Custom Structure`
5. `http://example.com/%post_id%/`

**Category or Tag archive pages**

Manually set a numeric slug for categories or tags via Backend:

1. Go to dashboard: `example.com/wp-admin/`
2. `Posts`->`Categories` or `Tags` Menu
3. Change the slug of the very category or tag to a numeric value

Comment: Already did that with posts, BUT tags/category URLs don't change, I still have mysitename.com/categoryname. I need mysitename.com/category/random number

Answer (score 0):

from paramlinks you can use for catagory and post as:
is esay to use

/%category%/%postname%/

For topics under more than 1 category within the site..